# URl not passing while running IE with web driver

Tags: webdriver

I am trying to run my scrip using web driver in IE. It is bringing up the browser but not passing the URL. While opening the browser it giving one message " This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server". I am using IE 9. Anybody has any idea what is happening here?

```
driver = new driver InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit, SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to("URL")
```

Comment: Yes, I know what is wrong.  You need to post a sample of your code for us to answer you for sure though...

Comment: I am writing driver = new driver InternetExplorerDriver(); driver.manage().window().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit, SECONDS); driver.navigate().to("URL");

Answer (score 0):

[Here is how I do it](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate) but I dont use Selenium RC... instead I use "pure" webdriver without the Selenium server:

```
public static void initializeBrowser( String type ) {
    if ( type.equalsIgnoreCase( "firefox" ) ) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } else if ( type.equalsIgnoreCase( "ie" ) ) {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
    driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(200, 10));
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
@Test
public void testWithPageObject() {      
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    GoogleSearchPage gs = new GoogleSearchPage();
    gs.setSearchString( searchString );
    selectInGoogleDropdown( ddMatch );  
    gs.clickSearchButton();
    waitTimer(3, 1000);
    clickElementWithJSE( "gbqlt" ); //click Google logo
    System.out.println("Done with test.");
}
```

One thing you will notice about this method is that the method that you call to goto the URL is different than when using the Selenium RC server.  See the link (above) to see my whole source code.

Comment: I am not using RC server. I am using pure Web Driver and ran your code but it is showing " after method, before method configuration fail.

Comment: I revised all my code today.  Try it again.  Run it with the included .bat file.